# I would like to create a sound and move the next activity after the ImageButton is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I have the code for the sound and the next activity. I do not know how to merge the two codes in order to execute them at the same time or in sequence.

```
package com.example.testmessages;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Add sound
        final MediaPlayer gunSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gunsound);
        ImageButton GunSound=(ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        GunSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gunSoundMP.start();
            }
        });

        //Image button to execute new Activity
        imageButton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intentLoadMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

                startActivity(intentLoadMain2Activity);
                gunSoundMP.start();
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Async task for this case.

Comment: As I am new to Java and Android studio. it is going take me a long time to use Async task, I can guess it is not tough to implement but can you probably show me how?

Comment: Your sound will start on button press but when to stop it? Is it long sound or you just want it for button tap sound?